# Console log promise nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I console.log the promise stored in a `promise` variable? I want to later assign that to a variable.

```
   function getMetricFilters() {
      const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

          exec("aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/ApiGateway  | jq -r .Metrics[].Dimensions[].Name | sort -u", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
                  //return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
              }
              if (stderr) {
                  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                  //return errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
              }
              console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
              //return okResponse(200, 'Migration successfully.');
            })
      })

      return promise
  }

   getMetricFilters() // I want the result of promise to be printed out or store it in a variable.
```

If I don't use the `getMetricFilters` function then it prints out `stdout` value. But if use the function, then nothing is printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a re-usable helper function that encapsulates `exec()` in a promise:

```
function execAsync(cmdline) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmdline, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) reject({error, stdout, stderr});
            else resolve({stdout, stderr});
        });
    });
}
```

Make a function for your cloudwatch command:

```
function getMetricFilters() {
    return execAsync("aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/ApiGateway  | jq -r .Metrics[].Dimensions[].Name | sort -u");
}
```

Use it:

```
getMetricFilters()
    .then(({stdout, stderr}) => {
        okResponse(200, 'Migration completed successfully.');
    })
    .catch(({error, stdout, stderr}) => {
        console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        errorResponse(500, 'Error running migration.');
    });
```

---

Mixing node-style callbacks and promises usually does not end well.

Since your `exports.handler` is a callback-based function, and all your other functions (like `exec()` and `lambda.invoke()`) are callback-based, I would keep the entire code callback-based.

[The `async` module](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html) offers useful helpers for this, such as `waterfall()`, which executes a list of asynchronous functions one after another, passing the result(s) of the previous to the next.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        // 1. parse SNS message (throw if invalid/unexpected)
        (callback) => {
            const sns = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
            console.log(1, sns);
            const Namespace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;
            if (Namespace !== "AWS/S3") throw new Error('Unexpected Namespace: ' + Namespace);
            const msgData = {
                Namespace: Namespace,
                MetricName: sns.Trigger.MetricName,
                BucketName: sns.Trigger.Dimensions.find(where('name', 'BucketName')).value,
                StorageType: sns.Trigger.Dimensions.find(where('name', 'StorageType')).value
            };
            callback(null, msgData);
        },
        // 2. run cloudwatch command
        (msgData, callback) => {
            console.log(2, msgData);
            const cmdline = "aws cloudwatch list-metrics --Namespace AWS/ApiGateway | jq -r .Metrics[].Dimensions[].Name | sort -u";
            exec(cmdline, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null, msgData, stdout, stderr);
            });
        },
        // 3. run zabbixPy
        (msgData, stdout, stderr, callback) => {
            console.log(3, msgData, stdout);
            lambda.invoke({
                FunctionName: 'zabbixPy',
                InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
                LogType: 'Tail',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({
                    Host: msgData.Namespace.replace("/", "_"),
                    key: `AWS[${msgData.BucketName}_${msgData.StorageType}_${msgData.MetricName}]`,
                    Value: "1"
                })
            }, callback);
        },
        // 4. next step...
        (zabbixResponse, callback) => {
            console.log(4, zabbixResponse.Payload);
            // ...
            callback(null, 'All done.');
        },
    ], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            context.fail(err);
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result); // 'All done.'
        // don't forget to call the main callback here
    });
};
```

The alternative would be to convert *all* asynchronous functions in that code path to promise-based functions. Not sure if that's less work.

Comment: Still nothing prints out. It bypasses `getMetricFilters().then and catch` and executes the code after that which are other things in the code.

Comment: It seems like if I remove all the code after `getMetricFilters().then and catch` then it works fine. Can't I have any other code after the function?

Comment: @John Yes. That's called "asynchronous code". You did not expect that it would *wait* at `getMetricFilters()`, did you?

Comment: Hmm. yea seems like the rest of the code is executed before the `getMetricFilters()`. What should I do to ensure `getMetricFilters()` should execute first?

Comment: Move "the rest of the code" into the callback for `getMetricFilters()`.

Comment: @John Also, what is the rest of the code? Your function looks like a request handler for an HTTP API. The last thing it will ever do is `okResponse()` or `errorResponse()`. What else would come after this in an HTTP request?

Comment: That works but doesn't look good. Because `function execAsync` and the code you sent is already inside `exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) { ... ` and then I have to work with `event` and also invoke other functions. No other alternatives to make the getMetricFilters execute first? I'll update the question to show the full code.

Comment: `okResponse()` and `errorRespone()` isn't needed for me. I'll update the question to show full code.

Comment: Updated the question to show full code. I'm trying to change everything after the promise section. I'm trying to test promise so I can write another function instead of all the if conditions. But at the end, I intend to invoke another lambda function and also make use of the event  from handler function

Comment: @John That's pretty confused code. Don't mix callback-based code (`function(event, context, callback)`) and promises, that rarely ends well.

Comment: I'm rewriting this, hang on.

Comment: @John See updated answer, there's a suggestion how to do it.

Comment: @John I've fat-fingered the argument order, see latest edit.

Comment: Alright. Testing it

Comment: @John The `async` module is solid, but it's still worthwhile to think about converting everything to promise-based functions, and then working with native `async`/`await`. Makes nicer code overall. I'm pretty sure that `aws-sdk` already offers a promise-based API, and for things like `exec()` it's not hard to write (or find) wrappers. It depends on the rest of your application how many more changes would be required.

Comment: Got it. Btw do you have a answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70064048/8445363

Comment: @John Are you asking how to split a string?