# Convert nodejs exec output to array

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I convert the shell command output to an array so I can print variables as `uniqueMetrics[0]`, `uniqueMetrics[1]` etc?

```
const uniqueMetrics = await execShellCommand('aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/ApiGateway  | jq -r .Metrics[].Dimensions[].Name | sort -u')

console.log(uniqueMetrics);
```

`output:`

```
ApiId
ApiName
Stage
```

It seems the data is returned as follows with `\r` and `\n`.

```
[ 'ApiId\r\nApiName\r\nStage\r\n' ]
```

So I'm guessing I'd need to search and replace these strings first. Am I thinking right?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use String.split() function:

```
let uniqueMetricsArray = uniqueMetrics.split('\r\n');
```

For better compatibility, it might make sense to make it work for both \r\n and just \n using RegExp:

```
let uniqueMetricsArray = uniqueMetrics.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Comment: It returns an empty array value as well. Any idea how to fix that as well? `[ 'ApiId', 'ApiName', 'Stage', '' ]`

Comment: @John `filter` the result or `trim` the input string.